# Python - Loop through lists and join them when they match

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict of lists. I have to loop through join them where possible. When joining them I have to add two columns together. I can either use the dict or list. Depending on what is easiest/recommended.

e.g.

| id | name | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hotel1 | 22-11-22 | 90 |
| 2 | hotel2 | 22-11-22 | 90 |
| 3 | hotel3 | 22-11-22 | 90 |
| 4 | hotel1 | 23-11-22 | 10 |
| 5 | hotel2 | 23-11-22 | 60 |
| 6 | hotel3 | 23-11-22 | 90 |

So I want to loop through the dict and provide the following outcome:

```
{
    "hotelName": "hotel1",
    "date": "22-11-22",
    "value": "100"
}
{
    "hotelName": "hotel2",
    "date": "22-11-22",
    "value": "150"
}
{
    "hotelName": "hotel3",
    "date": "22-11-22",
    "value": "180"
}
```

Any tips of guidance is welcome

I tried looping through the lists, but I can only output

```
{
    "hotelName": "hotel1",
    "date": "22-11-22",
    "value": "90"
}
{
    "hotelName": "hotel2",
    "date": "22-11-22",
    "value": "90"
}
{
    "hotelName": "hotel3",
    "date": "22-11-22",
    "value": "90"
}
{
    "hotelName": "hotel1",
    "date": "23-11-22",
    "value": "10"
}
{
    "hotelName": "hotel2",
    "date": "23-11-22",
    "value": "60"
}
{
    "hotelName": "hotel3",
    "date": "23-11-22",
    "value": "90"
}
```

Comment: please rewrite your question, it doesn't make sense currently

Comment: Also post the dict of lists please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab at it =)

```
hotels = {}
for ind,row in df.iterrows():
    hotel = row['name']
    if hotel in hotels:
        hotels[hotel]['value'] += row['value']
        hotels[hotel]['date'].append(row['date'])
    else:
        hotels[hotel] = {
            'value': row['value'],
            'date': [row['date']]
        }
print(hotels)
```

Outputs:

```
{'hotel1': {'value': 100, 'date': ['22.11.2022', '23.11.2022']},
 'hotel2': {'value': 150, 'date': ['22.11.2022', '23.11.2022']},
 'hotel3': {'value': 180, 'date': ['22.11.2022', '23.11.2022']}}
```